# How to remove unwanted string from column?

Tags: python, pandas, series

One of my columns df["reviews"] has reviews in it but only some reviews end with the string "Was this information helpful?...." 
So if my row contains this string, I want to get rid of the last 42 characters [:-42] which includes Was this information helpful?

how can I do this in Pandas 
Tried this but it isn't working

```
def remove_unwanted(a):
    if "Was this information helpful" in a:
        print(a[:-42])   
    else:
        print("False")
        
# column without yes and no in complaint body
df['cleaned_reviews'] = df.apply(lambda row: remove_unwanted(row['reviews']), axis = 1)
```

Comment: your function needs to `return` rather than `print()` in order to make it apply an effect on the dataframe

Comment: @oskros changed it to return a[:-42] It says TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable, my ending string also contains some numbers, could it be because of that?

Comment: it seems the values in `df['cleaned_reviews']` are not always strings, but sometimes a float instead, which is why you get that error. You could solve it by writing `str(a)[:-42]` instead

Comment: oh yes it did work now and also I realized it might have happened due to null values also, so I also applied notnull() and your answer, it solved 

Answer (score 0):

try this out, I guess this is what you're looking for

```
df['cleaned_reviews'] = df['reviews'].str.rstrip('Was this information helpful?')
```